# How can I create a code generator for specific file types for the Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

For example if I create a markdown file type I want visual studio to recognize (*.md) and ever time I save it convert it to HTML.

There are  tools that do this for :

- typescript to js
- coffeescript to js
- less to css
- sass to css

[image: example]

Just like *.ts expands to *.js

```
+-Player.ts
  |
  +-Player.js
```

I want to create a plugin/extension/whatever that expands
*.foo to *.bar

```
+-MyDoc.foo
  |
  +-MyDoc.bar
```

I want to keep the files linked and rebuild *.bar ever time *.foo is updated

I am just looking for info on how to get started, or an example implementation.

Comment: Maybe create a simple T4 template?  This is how ASP.NET scaffolds forms, and your scenario seems simpler than that.  Granted, you still have to push the button, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey T4 may work I am not experienced with them. I am looking for something that I can share with a dev team to help automate some of our common workflow. I wanted cost of admission for the consumer to be as low as possible, even if it is a little more investment upfront. I would really like to simply install a plugin or NuGet package and now have a new file type that VS recognizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T4 template is is what I used at the end of the day.